# Как в fancybox открывать другую страницу на необходимую высоту?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Сейчас открывается с прокруткой, но как сделать что бы на нужную открывался?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#iframe").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 1000,
        minHeight   : 2000,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '100%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#b").fancybox({ 
openEffect : 'none', 
closeEffect : 'none', 
type : 'iframe', 
width: 800, 
onComplete : function(e) { 
$('#fancybox-frame').load(function() { 
var iframe = document.getElementById("fancybox-frame"); 
var iframewrap = document.getElementById("fancybox-content"); 
console.log(iframe); 
console.log(iframewrap.height); 
iframewrap.style.height = iframe.contentDocument.body.scrollHeight + 30 + 'px'; 
iframe.style.height = iframe.contentDocument.body.scrollHeight + 'px'; 
}); 
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, поможет метод `$.fancybox.resize()`

Согласно документации:

> $.fancybox.resize Auto-resizes FancyBox height to match height of content